# Enable TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA IOS

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, encryption

I have a java server runing on port 9090 with SSL enabled. In my ios client app needs to connect to that server. My ios code is ,

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) hostname, port, &readStream, &writeStream);
    if (readStream && writeStream) {
        CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket , kCFBooleanTrue);
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

        //CFDataRef readdata = (CFDataRef) CFReadStreamCopyProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLContext);

        // Extract the SSLContextRef from the CFData
        SSLContextRef readsslContext = (SSLContextRef) CFReadStreamCopyProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLContext);
        //CFDataGetBytes(readdata, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(SSLContextRef)), (UInt8*)&readsslContext);
        SSLCipherSuite *readciphers = (SSLCipherSuite *)malloc(80 * sizeof(SSLCipherSuite));
        SSLGetSupportedCiphers(readsslContext, readciphers, 80);
        SSLSetEnabledCiphers(readsslContext, readciphers, 80);
        SSLGetEnabledCiphers(readsslContext, readciphers, 80);
        [self printCipher:readciphers];


        //CFDataRef data = (CFDataRef) CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLContext);

        // Extract the SSLContextRef from the CFData
        SSLContextRef sslContext = (SSLContextRef) CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLContext);
        //CFDataGetBytes(data, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(SSLContextRef)), (UInt8*)&sslContext);
        SSLCipherSuite *ciphers = (SSLCipherSuite *)malloc(80 * sizeof(SSLCipherSuite));
        SSLGetSupportedCiphers(sslContext, ciphers, 80);
        SSLSetEnabledCiphers(sslContext, ciphers, 80);

        inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;

        [inputStream setDelegate:self];
        outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
        [outputStream setDelegate:self];


        if (true)
        {
            int res1 = [inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
            int res2 = [outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
            NSLog(@"SEC TEST %d %d",res1,res2);


            NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
                                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                                      kCFNull,kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                                       kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv2, kCFStreamSSLLevel,
                                      nil];


            CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
            CFWriteStreamSetProperty((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
        }


        [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [inputStream open];

        [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [outputStream open];
    }

    if (readStream)
        CFRelease(readStream);

    if (writeStream)
        CFRelease(writeStream);
```

When i run this im getting error on java side.

```
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
SocketQueueReceiver:New Channel with socket:988500939
Socket Listener:9090, setSoTimeout(1000) called
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 75
*** ClientHello, SSLv3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1370064854 bytes = { 165, 24, 2, 48, 54, 154, 212, 242, 125, 211, 254, 197, 34, 77, 97, 201, 236, 50, 124, 169, 11, 152, 170, 30, 65, 185, 239, 0 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, Unknown 0x0:0x3d, Unknown 0x0:0x3c, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x67, Unknown 0x0:0x6b, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x3b, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, WRITE: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, called closeSocket()
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
2013-12-13 09:41:02 [Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358] ERROR com.enactor.core.queues.tcp.SocketQueueReceiver - Error reading socket
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:231)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:790)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:560)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:151)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at com.enactor.core.queues.tcp.SocketQueueBase$SocketReader.run(SocketQueueBase.java:620)
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, called close()
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, called closeInternal(true)
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, called close()
Socket Reader:/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:55358, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
```

I know cipher in the java side is TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Bu it is in ios supported ciphers not in enabled ciphers. I tried to enable that cipher but still it is not enabled.
How can i enable it?